# Using 'new CLASSNAME()' as array value in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

I'm making a converting script currently. I got 6 databases I need to use. I'm using PDO and my idea is to make everything with as least code as possible. I want to put my databases in an array.

I tried using:

```
private $databaseConnections = array(
    'db1' => new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db1;charset=utf8', 'user', 'pass'),
    'db2' => new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db2;charset=utf8', 'user', 'pass')
);
```

But I got the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'new' (T_NEW) in ... on line 11
```

Why can't I use new PDO as array value?

Comment: I just put this in a class. But netbeans already gives an syntax error on the line of db1. And on the page it gives the error I pasted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from the [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)

> declaration [of properties] may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value -- that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.

The solution to this is to define the property as an empty array, and either use a static setter (if you want to use the class statically) or instantiate the object and populate the array in your constructor

Comment: Thanks, that makes things clear for me. I'll accept the answer as soon as I can.